# JSON uploading to Tajo

Tags: json, apache-tajo

I have a flat JSON file which I am hoping to upload to Apache Tajo. I couldn't find JSON support in Tajo documentation. It is a flat JSON so I can just transform it as CSV but I am just wondering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a PMC member and a committer of Apache Tajo.
First of all, thanks for your interests in Tajo.

Unfortunately, Tajo doesn't support JSON files yet. However, you can find a related issue in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TAJO-1095. A patch is already waiting for the review, and this feature will be supported in the 0.9.1 release!

Sincerely, Jihoon